# Link Email Sent From Outlook to Specific SFDC Record

Tags: email, salesforce-for-outlook, outlook, emailtosalesforce

With Email to Salesforce you can use a BCC address to relate your emails to contacts and leads, and you can also have it relate to a contact's opportunities but in these cases, an email gets linked to all open opportunities belonging to a contact.

Is it possible in any way to have emails relate to one specific salesforce record?  For example, if a user emails a contact regarding a specific opportunity, can we somehow have that email link to the correct opportunity, rather than just relating it to the contact or all that contact's open opportunities?

Regards
Steven

Comment: Have you looked at Saleforce for Outlook and using the Side Panel?

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Implisit](https://www.implisit.com). Implisit connects to your email server as well as your Salesforce, and enters all relevant emails and calendar events into Salesforce **fully automatically**, attaching them to **Opportunities**, Accounts, Contacts and Leads. Implisit can also automatically create new contacts from email interactions.

DISCLAMER: I work for Implisit.

Answer (score 0):

You have the automatic relate options in Your Name-Setup-My Email Settings of All records, Most Recent Activity, Oldest Contact or you can choose to send all emails to My Unresolved Items for you to manually connect each email to your preferred Contact.

Comment: OK, looks like that's the only way.  Not quite what I was hoping for (was hoping there was some bcc address I could use to have it assign to any record) but I'll let the user know about this possible workaround.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a task with subject="email..." whoid=contactid and whatid=opprtunityid that way it will be related to the opprtunityid  and the contactid ...

Comment: This response would be better as a comment.  After you gain a few reputation points, you'll gain the ability to comment on other users' posts.